# Ionic - Google services json missing error

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

Just for testing purpose I'm trying to access native device features for which I've installed a blank new project and here's my `home.page.ts` file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Flashlight } from '@ionic-native/flashlight/ngx';

// import { Sim } from '@ionic-native/sim/ngx';

import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard/ngx';

@Component({

  selector: 'app-home',

  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',

  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],

})

export class HomePage {

  constructor(

    private flashlight: Flashlight,

    // private sim: Sim,

    private keyboard: Keyboard) {

    flashlight.switchOn();

    // sim.getSimInfo().then(info => {

    //   alert('Sim info: ' + info);

    // });

    keyboard.show();

  }

}
```

But when I run the app using Android studio, I get this error, even though I'm not using any of google services.
`File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it ionic`
Upon searching on google, people were telling to place the file obtained from firebase bla bla bla in src or root folder, but the question is I'm not using any of firebase feature or any other

Comment: It’s a warning, not an error

Comment: no, its error because my program fails to get compiled

Comment: Do you have any google/firebase plugin installed?

Comment: no, I don't have any plugin installed